# Finding the user that started workflow

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

Is there a way of finding out which user kicked off workflow? I would like an automatic decision at the start that if it's an admin user that has started the workflow that they can bypass the various different steps.

At the moment I have tried

```
CoreServiceClient.GetCurrentUser().Id
```

and

```
ActivityInstance.Performers.Fiers().Idref
```

Unfortunately both just refer to the Tridion user. I'm sure there must be a way and I've probably overlooked something very simple.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, not sure if this will help anyone else as I am sure that it probably isn't an actual problem for more experienced tridion users. But the id of the person who kicked off workflow was found using

```
ProcessInstance.Creator.IdRef;
```